# How do i get the URL of an <ice:graphicImage> element?

Tags: jsf, image, servlets, icefaces, javabeans

I'm trying to do a thumbnail gallery on my web page so that when one is clicked the full size image is shown. The images are stored in a backing bean and are shown with an  tag.

```
<li>
       <a href="????">
           <ice:graphicImage value="#{screenshot.image}" styleClass="thumb"/>
       </a>
</li>
```

When on the page, I see the images have addresses like /block/resource/MjY0OTc3Mzc1/ since they are served by the Icefaces blocking servlet.

What i need to know is how to get the link to the image so i can put it in the  element.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular situation, your best bet is likely JavaScript. When the page is finished loading, grab all `<img>` elements with classname `thumb`, extract the `src` attribute, locate the parent `<a>` and update its `href` attribute accordingly.

But I wouldn't do that. One, it's bad for user experience. Two, it won't work on JS disabled clients. Three, storing raw images in a bean is memory hogging. Rather store the images on local disk file system and link to them directly or, when outside the public webcontent or in a database, using a servlet. Then in your managed bean just have a collection of URL's to the images (or the servlet) and let the servlet stream them sequentially accordingly. You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html) a *basic* example of such a servlet and [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) a more advanced one supporting caching and resume.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply BalusC. 
After searching the around the web for solutions I ended up doing the first option since it is much simpler and with jQuery it was really easy to implement. Also since the images are stored in a request scoped bean and there's only 4 of them (images) I think memory consumption won't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to solve the problem.
I had this unordered list for my gallery:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{solutionBean.solution.screenshots}" var="screenshot">
                    <li>
                        <a href="gal" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" title="#{screenshot.description}">
                        <ice:graphicImage value="#{screenshot.image}" alt="#{screenshot.alternative}"
                                              height="135" width="130"/>
                        </a>
                    </li></ui:repeat>
```

And I added this script to replace the href elemnt in the hyperlink with the src element from the image:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("a[href^='gal']").each(function() {
                this.href = jQuery('img', this).attr("src");
            });
        });
```